# What words were used before "exist"?

Tags: etymology, old-english, middle-english

The word "exist" was [first used in English around 1568](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exist). The English must have had their own word for this before that. Which word did they use?

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/exist

Answer (score 3):

### [Ibeon](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED21588)

The verb mentioned by [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/exist#etymonline_v_29832) as being "often used". It was a form of "be".

From Chaucer, ?a1425(c1380):

> Although the prescience ne hadde nevere iben, yit algate..it is certein thing that the endes and bytydinges of thingis to comen scholden ben necessarie.

### [Be](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED4048)

The same verb you should know.

From Haile be þou hende, a1450:

> If synne ne were, Goddes moder ware þou noght.
>
> "If sin were not, God's mother were thou not."

### [Tain](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED44661)

Might be closer in meaning to "remain".

From *Wills Registered at York*, 1462

> It is my will yat my sister have..all ye malt yat is in ye new hous chaumbre and all ye whete yt tenes after my disces.
>
> "It is my will that my sister have..all the malt that is in the new house chamber and all the wheat that tains after my decease."

Comment: This was definitely easier to find than finding whatever non-Latinate word or words Old English used to use before Middle English imported the Latinate use of *use* would be. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/exist) gives the answer under the etymology of *exist*:

> c. 1600, from French *exister* (17c.), from Latin *existere/exsistere* "to step out, stand forth, emerge, appear; exist, be" (see existence). "The late appearance of the word is remarkable" [OED]. ***Middle English often used ibēn, ibeon (based on be) for "to exist."***

Here is one example from the *[Middle English Compendium](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED21588)*:

> And mani Miracle at Abindone for hire hath sethþe ***ibeo***. (*[South English Legendary: St. Edmund Rich of Abingdon](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/bibliography/BIB3168?rid=HYP.1414.19981211T105002)*)

It is not excluded that the word of French origin passed into English through the influence of the philosophical ideas of the 17th and 18th centuries:

> Some date the beginning of the Enlightenment back to the publication of René Descartes' *Discourse on the Method* in 1637, featuring his famous dictum, ***Cogito, ergo sum*** ("I think, therefore I am"). ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Enlightenment))

Note that here *am* is synonym of *exist* (which is the word used in the French version of the dictum (*Je pense, donc j'existe.*) In fact, some do translate it into English as ***I think, therefore I exist.***

[Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/cogito-ergo-sum) explains:

> ***cogito, ergo sum***, (Latin: “I think, therefore I am) dictum coined by the French philosopher René Descartes in his *Discourse on Method* (1637) as a first step in demonstrating the attainability of certain knowledge. It is the only statement to survive the test of his *[methodic doubt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_doubt)*. The statement is indubitable, as Descartes argued in the second of his six *Meditations on First Philosophy* (1641), because even if an all-powerful demon were to try to deceive him into thinking that he ***exists*** when he does not, he would have to ***exist*** in order for the demon to deceive him. Therefore, ***whenever he thinks, he exists.***

Answer (score 0):

From "Old English Translator"[1](https://www.oldenglishtranslator.co.uk/index.htm) (which is reliable)

In the sense of “There are/exist lions in Africa” / “There is/exists a man who can help you.” “Dragons do not exist.”

The verb was **wesan**

> **Verb** irregular **to be ; exist**
>
> **Present Tense**
>
> Sg. 1     ic/i eom – I am/exist
>
> 2     þu you eart –thou/you art/exist
>
> 3     he/hit/heo is - he/it/she is /exist
>
> Pl.   we/ge/hie sind|sindon & we/ye/they sind|sindon – We/you/they are
> /exist
>
> **Simple past:**
>
> Ic/i wæs
>
> þu - you wǣre
>
> he/hit/heo - he/it/she wæs
>
> we/ge/hie & we/ye/they wǣron
>
> **Subjunctive**
>
> Sg. sīe (present) wǣre (past)  Pl.    sīen (present) wǣren (past)
>
> **Participles**
>
> present participle (...ing) wesende   being/exisiting
>
> **Imperative** Sg.    wes, Pl.    wesaþ
>
> **Inflected Infinitive**: to wesenne